# Hibernate findAll(example) throws "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null"

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I'm currently having the following issue when trying to perform a find all using an Example with a matcher, code:

```
public List<AlumniProfile> getAllAlumniProfileByExample(AlumniProfile profileToFilterBy) {
    ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
            .withIgnoreCase()
            .withStringMatcher(ExampleMatcher.StringMatcher.CONTAINING);
    Example<AlumniProfile> example = Example.of(profileToFilterBy,matcher);
    return alumniProfileDAO.findAll(example);
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setWrappedInstance(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:195) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setWrappedInstance(BeanWrapperImpl.java:153) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setWrappedInstance(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:183) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.<init>(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:122) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.<init>(BeanWrapperImpl.java:103) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.util.DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.<init>(DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.java:36) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.getPredicates(QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.java:110) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.getPredicates(QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.getPredicate(QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository$ExampleSpecification.toPredicate(SimpleJpaRepository.java:812) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.applySpecificationToCriteria(SimpleJpaRepository.java:694) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:625) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:439) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at ar.org.pescar.services.AlumniProfileService.getAllAlumniProfileByExample(AlumniProfileService.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
at ar.org.pescar.controller.AlumniController.getAlumniBy(AlumniController.java:136) ~[classes/:na]
at ar.org.pescar.controller.AlumniController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$75bacf1b.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at ar.org.pescar.controller.AlumniController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2cea1e92.getAlumniBy(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at ar.org.pescar.security.service.JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter.java:71) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

My entity is:

```
@Entity
public class AlumniProfile {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8445943548965164378L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "alumni_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "alumni_seq", sequenceName = "alumni_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer id;

    private String telephone;
    private String alternativeTelephone;
    private String maximumEducation;
    private String pescarCenter;
    private String counselor;
    private Integer graduationYear;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Job currentJob;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Job> jobHistory;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Study currentStudy;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Study> studyHistory;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", unique=true)
    private User user;


    public AlumniProfile() {
        this.jobHistory = new ArrayList<>();
        this.studyHistory = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public AlumniProfile(String telephone, String alternativeTelephone,
                         String maximumEducation, String pescarCenter,
                         String counselor, Integer graduationYear) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.alternativeTelephone = alternativeTelephone;
        this.maximumEducation = maximumEducation;
        this.pescarCenter = pescarCenter;
        this.counselor = counselor;
        this.graduationYear = graduationYear;
        this.jobHistory = new ArrayList<>();
        this.studyHistory= new ArrayList<>();
    }


    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public String getAlternativeTelephone() {
        return alternativeTelephone;
    }

    public String getMaximumEducation() {
        return maximumEducation;
    }

    public String getPescarCenter() {
        return pescarCenter;
    }

    public String getCounselor() {
        return counselor;
    }

    public Integer getGraduationYear() {
        return graduationYear;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Optional<Job> getCurrentJob() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(currentJob);
    }

    public void setCurrentJob(Job currentJob) {
        this.currentJob = currentJob;
    }

    public void addToJobHistory(Job historyJob) {
        this.jobHistory.add(historyJob);
    }

    public List<Job> getJobHistory() {
        return new ArrayList<>(this.jobHistory);
    }

    public void setCurrentStudy(Study study) {
        this.currentStudy = study;
    }

    public Optional<Study> getCurrentStudy() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(currentStudy);
    }

    public void addToStudyHistory(Study study) {
        this.studyHistory.add(study);
    }

    public List<Study> getStudyHistory() {
        return this.studyHistory;
    }

    //To avoid returning the user object.
    @JsonIgnore
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

This was previously working when the entity only contained:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "alumni_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "alumni_seq", sequenceName = "alumni_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Integer id;

private String telephone;
private String alternativeTelephone;
private String maximumEducation;
private String pescarCenter;
private String counselor;
private Integer graduationYear;
```

But after adding all of the changes I ran the tests and I'm getting this response, I tried executing the post request from Powershell/Postman and from MockMVC in the tests and I get the same result. This is the data that gets loaded to the H2 DB at runtime:

```
insert into ALUMNI_PROFILE (ID, TELEPHONE, ALTERNATIVE_TELEPHONE, MAXIMUM_EDUCATION, PESCAR_CENTER, COUNSELOR, GRADUATION_YEAR, USER_ID) values (21, 1509276274, 1561494945, 'Universidad', 'Cordoba', 'Calla', 2001, 20);
insert into ALUMNI_PROFILE (ID, TELEPHONE, ALTERNATIVE_TELEPHONE, MAXIMUM_EDUCATION, PESCAR_CENTER, COUNSELOR, GRADUATION_YEAR, USER_ID) values (22, 1500479177, 1524864295, 'Maestria', 'Cordoba', 'Calla', 1993, 21);
insert into ALUMNI_PROFILE (ID, TELEPHONE, ALTERNATIVE_TELEPHONE, MAXIMUM_EDUCATION, PESCAR_CENTER, COUNSELOR, GRADUATION_YEAR, USER_ID) values (23, 1512050663, 1589763064, 'Maestria', 'Lanus', 'Berk', 2000, 22);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: seems you haven't specified on which property `StringMatcher.CONTAINING` has to be applied.

Comment: I needed this to work with all properties and it was previously working without this specified, Does it become necessary once you add relations with other entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the error,

As this entity has relations with other entities and this in the probe are empty it throws the "Target object must not be null", all I needed to add was:

```
.withIgnorePaths("currentJob","jobHistory","currentStudy","studyHistory","user");
```

To the `ExampleMatcher` so it would not check the entities. Now it works like before.

Final code:

```
ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
            .withIgnoreCase()
            .withStringMatcher(ExampleMatcher.StringMatcher.CONTAINING)
            .withIgnorePaths("currentJob","jobHistory","currentStudy","studyHistory","user");
Example<AlumniProfile> example = Example.of(profileToFilterBy,matcher);
return alumniProfileDAO.findAll(example);
```